# scrapy items , how to load in to other fields

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a spider that extracts business hours and it works fine. How ever I am not able to hide the item values that were passed on to another item dict not show again in the final out put. Can some one help me in this

### My item file:

```
class WrapItemList(scarpy.Item):
    mon = scrapy.Field()
    tue = scrapy.Field()
    wed = scrapy.Field()
    thu= scrapy.Field()
    sat= scrapy.Field()
    sun= scrapy.Field()
    businessHours=scrapy.Field()
```

### My Spider

for list in listings:

```
il = MySiteLoader(selector=details,item=WrapListItem())
il.add_xpath('mon','.........')
il.add_xpath('tue','.........')
il.add_xpath('wed','.........')
il.add_xpath('thu','.........')
il.add_xpath('fri','.........')
il.add_xpath('sat','.........')
il.add_xpath('sat','.........')
il.add_value('businessHours',"Mon":il.get_output_value('mon'),"Tue":il.get_output_value('tue'),"Wed":il.get_output_value('wed'),"Thu":il.get_output_value('thu'),"Fri":il.get_output_value('fri'),"Sat":il.get_output_value('sat'),"Sun":il.get_output_value('sun')})
```

### My Current output

```
    mon: 10 AM - 6 PM tue: 10 AM - 6 PM wed: 10 AM - 6 PM thu: 10 AM - 6 PM fri: 10 AM - 6 PM sat: 10    AM - 6 PM sun: 10 AM - 6 PM

Business Hours :{mon: 10 AM - 6 PM tue: 10 AM - 6 PM, wed: 10 AM - 6 PM, thu: 10 AM - 6 PM, fri: 10 AM - 6 PM, sat: 10 AM - 6 PM. sun: 10 AM - 6 PM}
```

### My Expected output

```
Business Hours :{mon: 10 AM - 6 PM tue: 10 AM - 6 PM, wed: 10 AM - 6 PM, thu: 10 AM - 6 PM, fri: 10 AM - 6 PM, sat: 10 AM - 6 PM. sun: 10 AM - 6 PM}
```

Comment: Please provide your full spider code and the URL of the site being scrapped so we can check the code and test if necessary. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all. I was able to solve with some help from Github. The following code worked fine.

```
from scrapy.contrib.loader.processor import TakeFirst
[...]
il.add_value('businessHours', "Mon": il.get_xpath('.....', TakeFirst()), ...)
```